# Pygame Text Anchor Right

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Can I put a right-anchor in a text in pygame? Like this:

```
|"Text justify left."|  #(default in pygame)
|"Text justify right"|

#and when delete the word "Text", text stay in the right position:

|" justify left."| #anchor in left (default)
    |" justify right"| #anchor in right
```

My func:

```
    def messageScreen(self, message = "Default message", color = (0, 0, 0), pos = [50, 50]):
        screenText = self.font.render(message, True, color)
        self.screen.blit(screenText, pos)

    self.messageScreen("my text", (200, 100, 0))
    pygame.display.update()
```

There is a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`blit()` can use `pygame.Rect()` as object position. And `pygame.Rect()` has attribute `.right` so you can set `.right` and `Rect()` calculates correct `.x`

```
text = self.font.render(message, True, color)
text_rect = text.get_rect()
text_rect.right = 150 # align to right to 150px

self.screen.blit(text, text_rect)
```

BTW: You can copy `right` from other object.

```
# first text draw normally

text_1 = self.font.render(message_1, True, color)
text_1_rect = text_1.get_rect()

# second text

text_2 = self.font.render(message_2, True, color)
text_2_rect = text_2.get_rect()

text_2_rect.right = text_1_rect.right # align to right side of first text
```